# How can I solve the error "Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type" on STM32 board?

Tags: stm32, hardware, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I tried to run the benchmarking code at [here](https://github.com/mupq/polymul-z2mx-m4)

When I try to flash the binary like `st-flash write benchmark-kindi256342.bin 0x8000000`, an error occurs as following.

```
st-flash 1.7.0-233-gc7bcb52
Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type
2023-01-06T14:53:14 INFO common.c: STM32F4x5_F4x7: 192 KiB SRAM, 8193 KiB flash in at least 16 KiB pages.
file benchmark-kindi256342.bin md5 checksum: 3fa07ff1b92e1f518836528be256b098, stlink checksum: 0x00be4029
2023-01-06T14:53:14 INFO common_flash.c: Attempting to write 98588 (0x1811c) bytes to stm32 address: 134217728 (0x8000000)
EraseFlash - Sector:0x0 Size:0x4000 -> Flash page at 0x8000000 erased (size: 0x4000)
EraseFlash - Sector:0x1 Size:0x4000 -> Flash page at 0x8004000 erased (size: 0x4000)
EraseFlash - Sector:0x2 Size:0x4000 -> Flash page at 0x8008000 erased (size: 0x4000)
EraseFlash - Sector:0x3 Size:0x4000 -> Flash page at 0x800c000 erased (size: 0x4000)
EraseFlash - Sector:0x4 Size:0x10000 -> Flash page at 0x8010000 erased (size: 0x10000)

2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flashloader.c: Starting Flash write for F2/F4/F7/L4
2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flash_loader.c: Successfully loaded flash loader in sram
2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flash_loader.c: Clear DFSR
2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flash_loader.c: Clear CFSR
2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flash_loader.c: Clear HFSR
2023-01-06T14:53:17 INFO flashloader.c: enabling 32-bit flash writes
2023-01-06T14:53:19 INFO common_flash.c: Starting verification of write complete
2023-01-06T14:53:19 ERROR common_flash.c: Verification of flash failed at offset: 0
stlink_fwrite_flash() == -1
```

The first error is `Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type` and the second is `ERROR common_flash.c: Verification of flash failed at offset: 0`.

How can I solve this error?

I use STM32F407G board and linux using VMWare.

I tried
`st-flash --connect-under-reset --reset write build/h7a3zi_test.bin 0x08000000`,
but it doesn't work.

Also I tried re-plug all the cables and it doesn't work too.

Comment: What flash type are you using?

Comment: @TimRoberts these addresses refer to the internal flash.

Comment: Don't use st-flash.  Use the official tools from the part manufacturer, distributed as part of STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: @TomV I have done what the README says at https://github.com/mupq/polymul-z2mx-m4 here. He used st-flash to run. I wonder I can run the code with the official tools you said.